# Israel tst 2011 geometrical inequality

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, geometric-inequalities

Inside an equilateral triangle of area $S$ lies a point, whose distances to the vertices are $x,y, z$. 
Prove that $xy + yz + zx \geq \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} S$

I haven't got any idea yet. But I guess Fermat's point can be helpful....($x+y+z\ge \sqrt{3}a$)

Comment: Just a thought, but when you put one point of the triangle at the Origin, one point at (x,0) then the third point can be expressed in terms of x? That way, perhaps the problem can be reduced to a single variable?

Comment: @imranfat:  you can certainly scale the triangle to have unit sides and position it at $(0,0), (1,0), (1/2,\sqrt3/2)$, but there is still a 2D space for the point.

Comment: I mean not $(1,0)$ but keep it variable $(x,0)$ so that any equilateral of any size can be represented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let our point be a origin of the Gauss plane, $\Delta ABC$ be our triangle,

$A(a)$, $B(b)$ and $C(c)$.
Since $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(b-c)(c-a)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b-a^2c)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)}=-1$, we obtain:

$1=|\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(b-c)(c-a)}|\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{|a|\cdot|b|}{|b-c|\cdot|c-a|}=\frac{xy+xz+yz}{AB^2}$

Done!